# How to get compilation option of Intel C Compile in Runtime?

Tags: icc

I made some performance experiment. I want to enable/disable autovectorization in ICC.

I add -no-vec option but is it possible to make some debug printing like:

```
printf("%s", VEC_ENABLED ? "vectorized" : "not vectorized");
```

Are there any embedded ICC macro to do this?

**UPD**: VEC_ENABLED is just an example and not real macro. There is no such macro in [docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524490).

Simple workaround for make file is:

```
# by default vectorization enabled
#OPTFLAGS= -DVEC_ENABLED=1
# vectorization disabled
OPTFLAGS= -no-vec -DVEC_ENABLED=0
CFLAGS=... $(OPTFLAGS)
```

But still look for better way.

**UPD2**: from Anoop Madhusoodhanan Prabha - to disable both auto and explicit vectorization it is necessary to use 2 flags: -no-vec -no-simd

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Why should there be something built in for this?

Comment: At least some compiler options can be accessed via macros. For example `__MIC__` macro is defined when program compiled for MIC architecture. Maybe it is common practice and it is easy to get other compile options from macro.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were saying that `VEC_ENABLED` actually existed, not that it was an example of what you'd *like* to have. Unfortunately, looking through [the documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524490), I don't see any such predefined macro.

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't expose any macro which reflects the status of auto-vectorization based on the compiler options passed. One important thing to keep in mind is that -no-vec will only disable auto-vectorization. If you happen to use #pragma omp simd (OpenMP SIMD) in your program, the vectorization for those loops will still happen. To totally disable vectorization (both auto-vectorization and explicit vectorization), please use compiler options -no-vec -no-simd.

Comment: Thank you for your remark about full vectorization disabling.